Quadratic upper bound for strongly convex functions with point constraints
Question:
Consider a $ \mu $-strongly convex function $ f(x) $ with the following properties:

$ f(0) = 0 $
$ f(\pm 1) = 1 $
$ 0 $ is a global minimum of $ f $

By definition, a function $ f(x) $ is $ \mu $-strongly convex if for all $ x, x_0 $ in the interval of interest (in this case, $[-1,1]$):
$$
f(x) \geq f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x - x_0) + \frac{\mu}{2}(x - x_0)^2.
$$
Given this setup, I am wondering if there is a way to establish an upper bound on $ f(x) $ in the interval $[-1,1]$, ideally a quadratic bound. It seems that the function must grow slowly (sub-linearly) near $ x = 0 $ due to the curvature imposed by strong convexity and the constraint $ f(1) = 1 $.
Additionally, how would this bound depend on the parameter $ \mu $?

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.
